# ChangeNotifierProxyProvider with an existing ChangeNotifier

Tags: flutter, provider, flutter-change-notifier

I want to know how to use ChangeNotifierProxyProvider with an existing ChangeNotifier?

The documentation clearly says DO use ChangeNotifierProvider.value to provide an existing ChangeNotifier.

BUT

ChangeNotifierProxyProvider doesn't have a .value method so is it ok to provide my existing ChangeNotifier to the create method?

```
ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Model1, Model2>(
          create: (ctx) => model2,
          update: (ctx, model1, previousModel2) =>
              previousModel2..setModel1(Model1),
        ),
```